# How to handle HTTPS login in JIRA

Tags: python, jira

I am new to python,

```
basic_auth=('username', 'password')
```

Can someone give me a basic example to how to https login to jira.

Tried below but that doesn't work for me:

> > > jira_options = {'server': "https://jira-stability.qualcomm.com/jira/browse"}
> > >       jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('username',"pwd"))

```
WARNING:root:bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],) while doing GET https://jira-stability.qualcomm.com/jira/browse/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{u'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', u'X-Atlassian-Token': u'no-check', u'Cache-Control': u'no-cache', u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, 'params': None}]
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET https://jira-stability.qualcomm.com/jira/browse/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 10s. Err: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

Thanks
Shashi

Answer (score 1):

Try this out  :

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener.open('http://www.somewebpage.com/login.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.somewebpage.com/home.php')
print resp.read()
```

It's a sample code for login in to any page and get the response using python

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that is throwing error as :    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required

Comment: You might be doing it from a machine which has proxy enabled so your request is going through the proxy  which needs your machine name and password for authentication. . Normally in office their is  proxy enabled